# Can we hide the legal text in iPhone 5 (apple) maps?

Tags: iphone, maps, iphone-5

Can we hide the **Legal** text in apple maps on the bottom left? (Previously it was the text **Google**)

Will the application get rejected?

Comment: yes you can hide it by increasing the size of your mapview. Thus it won't be rejected by apple.

Comment: @Foram Mukund Shah thanks for the reply.. any official links or something..

Comment: sorry. No idea for that.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about legal issues / Apple App Store policy, not programming or software development. See the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can at least get into trouble for doing so, if your app "survives" the approval process, it will be probably only because the reviewer missed it! I have already been through enough and will never hide any apple addition to the map :) ...

Answer (score 1):

From the **iOS Developer Program License Agreement** (dated Jun 10, 2013), in Attachment 6, section 2.1,

> Your Application must not remove, obscure or alter Apple’s or its licensors’ copyright notices, trademarks, or any other proprietary rights or legal notices, documents or hyperlinks that may appear in or be provided through the Apple Maps Service.

So I guess you should not hide the Legal text.

<sup>Disclaimer: I am not a lawyer. Please do not take this as formal legal advice.</sup>

<sup>*You can find the agreement in the **iOS Dev Center** → **Member Center** → **Your Account** → **Legal Agreements**, if you have joined the iOS Developer Program.*</sup>